# I am working on my first mobile app and I cannot get the right navbar button to work

Tags: jquery-mobile, navbar, dreamweaver

I am using Dreamweaver CS6 and I have attached the code below.  I updated all of the jquery files to the latest releases.  When I go in to live view I can click on both of the first two buttons but the third button will not work on either page and it does not have a clean edge on the right.  Is there something wrong with the css or the code itself.  Thanks

I am using Dreamweaver CS6 and I have attached the code below.  I updated all of the jquery files to the latest releases.  When I go in to live view I can click on both of the first two buttons but the third button will not work on either page and it does not have a clean edge on the right.  Is there something wrong with the css or the code itself.  Thanks

```
<!--Safety Home Page Starts Here -->
<div data-role="page" id="safety_home" data-theme="c">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="c">
    <h1>GGM Mobile</h1>
    <div data-role="navbar" data-theme="c"><ul>
      <li><a href="#safety_home" class="ui-btn-active">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#safety_topic">Topics</a></li>
      <li><a href="#safety_report">Report</a></li>
    </ul></div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content" data-theme="c">
    <p>Home</p>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer" data-theme="c">
    <h4>Gothic Grounds Management, Inc. &copy; 2012</h4>
  </div>
</div>
    <!--Safety Home Page Ends Here -->
    <!--Safety Topic Page Starts Here -->
<div data-role="page" id="safety_topic" data-theme="c">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="c">
    <h1>GGM Mobile</h1>
    <div data-role="navbar" data-theme="c"><ul>
      <li><a href="#safety_home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#safety_topic" class="ui-btn-active">Topic</a></li>
      <li><a href="#safety_report">Report</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content" data-theme="c">
    <p>Topics</p>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer" data-theme="c">
    <h4>Gothic Grounds Management, Inc. &copy; 2012</h4>
  </div>
    <!--Safety Topics Page Ends Here -->
    <!--Safety Incidents Page Starts Here -->
<div data-role="page" id="safety_report" data-theme="c">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="c">
    <h1>GGM Mobile</h1>
    <div data-role="navbar" data-theme="c"><ul>
      <li><a href="#safety_home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#safety_topic">Topics</a></li>
      <li><a href="#safety_report" class="ui-btn-active">Report</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content" data-theme="c">
    <p>Topics</p>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer" data-theme="c">
    <h4>Gothic Grounds Management, Inc. &copy; 2012</h4>
  </div>
    <!--Safety Incident Page Ends Here -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah your second and third page has no closing `</div>` tag. You may want to try and use validators to help spot issues like this. Here is the type of thing that you see when you run your code through a validator.

Line 38, Column 56: Unclosed element div.

`<div data-role="page" id="safety_report" data-theme="c">`

Line 20, Column 55: Unclosed element div.

`<div data-role="page" id="safety_topic" data-theme="c">`

**HTML5 Validators**

1. http://validator.w3.org/
2. http://html5.validator.nu/

I hope this helps.